# Show desktop shortcut on Pantheon

Tags: elementary-theme, wingpanel, show-desktop, pantheon, plank

I'm using Elementary OS's Pantheon Desktop Environment in Ubuntu 12.04.

What is the shortcut to show the desktop?

How can I add Show Desktop icon on Wingpanel or on Plank Doc?

Comment: I have done a bash script which uses Xwindow utilities such as xwininfo, xdotool and wmctrl.
All details and full Code of the script at
[http://fpkanarias.blogspot.com.es/2017/12/elementary-os-script-para-mostrar.html](http://fpkanarias.blogspot.com.es/2017/12/elementary-os-script-para-mostrar.html)

Answer (score 1):

on desktop you can't put launcher. elementary does't support "have file manager handle desktop"
in dock (plank), open the app and his launcher is been show in dock. right click on icon and in meny go to "keep to dock".
in wingpanel, same as unity panel, is possibe  via dconf-editor some, but launcher to panel not. indicators in panel & message meny work like in unity panel

Comment: You also missed the point of the question, he's not asking how to enable the Desktop he's how asking to add a shortcut to Plank to show the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

1. install `elementary Tweaks`

> ```
> sudo apt-add-repository ppa:versable/elementary-update
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install elementary-tweaks
> ```

2. Go to `System settings` -> `Tweaks` -> `Plank` -> `Show Desktop Icon`

Comment: Unfortunately, does not work (anymore?):  
    `W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found`  
    `W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found`  
and then of course:  
`E: Unable to locate package elementary-tweaks`